# Spin up "VSTS on-demand Agent" when there is a new build request and delete the docker container once the build is done

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

Can anyone guide me how can i setup On-Demand VSTS agents using the VSTS Ubuntu docker image. Are there any plugins which spins up the agents when there is a new build request and destroy the agent once build is done ?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think yo can achieve that.

Generally when you queue a build it needs an existing agent... That means select agent automatically or you need to set the demands to specify the specific agent... Otherwise the build will be failed...

But based on your description you need to deploy the agent first then use it for current build...

However you can reference below thread for removing the unused Docker containers from the registry:

[Is there a VSTS build task to remove unused Docker containers from the registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773679/is-there-a-vsts-build-task-to-remove-unused-docker-containers-from-the-registry)